# Simple MySql conditional SELECT Query Problem with BOOLEAN

Tags: mysql, select, conditional-statements, boolean

I've got a pretty simple issue here which I can't get to work.

```
SELECT * FROM pto_products WHERE blacklist IS NULL AND pzn LIKE '%$term%' OR name LIKE '%$term%'
```

Columns:
blacklist is a MySql BOOL Field, TINYINT
If the Record is blacklisted the value is set to 1 otherwise NULL

pzn is the Index and

```
INT name VARCHAR(255)
```

The Issue I have is that I allways receive all records including the blacklisted ones when I run this query. Does anyone know how I maybe need to group the conditions to achieve the needed result so the blacklisted records are excluded?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM pto_products WHERE blacklist IS NULL AND (pzn LIKE '%$term%' OR name LIKE '%$term%')
```